# Better way to model these edges?

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, topology

i have some trouble with using subsurface modifier on this specific model. Some Edges are beautiful how i want it, but there is some tricky thing about this specific model which makes it impossible to add loop cuts from a certain 'direction'. It seems that i didn't fully understand how to make the right topology. Is there a way to do it better?

Picture 1 shows the edge which is to soft, pictures 2 shows the problematic topology. Picture 3 and 4 shows the good part which works fine because i can shift loop cuts from the bottom to the edge like how it should be obviously. Picture 5 and 6 shows that it is not a good solution to add loop cuts between because it create a noticeable 'dig'. I want a sharp edge (yellow) while maintaining an even curvature (blue)

Thanks!

[image: problematic edge 1]

[image: problematic edge 2]

[image: good edge 1]

[image: good edge 2]

[image: not a good solution]

[image: not a good solution 2]

Comment: It's hard to advise you how to proceed without knowing something about what you find problematic with your model, or what your desired result is.

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/ptqHkrK) what you mean? (Feel free to use that  image if it is, and it helps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Edge Creases. Select the edges you want the Subdivision modifier to keep sharp.

Edge crease by either :

- Right Click > Edge Crease
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- Edge > Edge Crease

[image]